# Not exiting first keypress event when parent function gets fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

## Problem

I have a `.keypress()` event inside of a `.click()` event.  The first time the user clicks on the element, everything works fine, but subsequent clicks trigger the `.keypress()` event again without "closing" the first one.  I've tried adding `event.cancelBubble = true;` and an empty return statement to break out of the function, but it hasn't worked because predictably, the rest of the code in that execution doesn't get executed but the event is still active and a key press could still trigger it.  Is there a way to close the `.keypress()` event when foo gets clicked?

## Code

```
$(foo).click(function(){
    //Do stuff
    $(foo).keypress(function(event) {
        //Do stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: could you post JSFiddle? Also share what are you trying to achieve ultimately.

Comment: Definitely explain what you're trying to achieve. While the answers below may solve the exact question you're asking, I'm highly suspicious of the approach you're taking.

Comment: Okay @pratikwebdev and @maxedison, the application of this is in a hangman game.  Once the user clicks on a category , a `.keypress()` event is triggered so the user can enter a letter.  Before I got @dann's answer, the `.keypress()` event wouldn't close from the first time it was called, but instead each time foo was clicked both the latest `.keypress()` event in latest click would be listening, and all of the open `.keypress()` events from previous times.

Comment: Here's the "non-simplified" version with @dann's answer incorporated: https://jsfiddle.net/cpk3x23f/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cpk3x23f/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you mean `keypress` called more than once?
in your code, every time you click foo, a new anonymous function will be added to `keypress` event.

unbind the previous `keypress` event handler before binding new handler

```
$(foo).click(function(){    
    //Do stuff    
    $(foo).off('keypress').on('keypress', function(event) {    
        //Do stuff    
    });    
});
```

Comment: The `.one()` method does the same thing but is a bit more concise: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Side note: [Namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) can be helpful with such scenarios, to avoid interrupting unrelated event bindings.

Comment: @maxedison `.one()` doesn't prevent multiple bindings, only multiple invocations. They can still build up until the next occurrence of the event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but I think you want to turn off the keypress after the first click.  This should toggle it though you may want to make the `pressed` var global; maybe.

```
$(foo).click(function(){
    //Do stuff
    var pressed = false;
    $(foo).keypress(function(event) {
        if(!pressed){
            //Do stuff
            pressed = true;
        } else {
            event.off();
            pressed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

The key here is `event.off()` which will remove the listener.